# Bind css column-count property for lists to bootstrap grid classes responsively

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and i have a list with ~1000 Items.
The data is fetched from a database with a single query.
I'd like to adapt the displaying of the list with the css column-count property in three ways, namely by the bootstrap grid classes col-xs, col-sm and col-md.

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

When the browser fits the col-md specification, column-count should be set to 3. (So the list is displayed with 3 columns on large screens.)

```
Item 1  | Item 3  | Item 5
Item 2  | Item 4  | Item 6
```

When the browser fits the col-sm specification, column-count should be set to 2. (So the list is displayed with 2 columns on e.g. tablet screens.)

```
Item 1  | Item 4 
Item 2  | Item 5
Item 3  | Item 6
```

When the browser fits the col-xs specification, column-count should be set to 1. (So the list is displayed with 1 column on small screens.)

```
Item 1 
Item 2  
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

**Question:** How can i bind the css column-count property to the bootstrap grid classes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works :**

```css
ul {
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}

@media(min-width: 480px){
  ul{
      -webkit-column-count: 1;
      -moz-column-count: 1;
      column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
  ul{
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      -moz-column-count: 2;
      column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 992px){
  ul{
      -webkit-column-count: 3;
      -moz-column-count: 3;
      column-count: 3;
    }
}
div{width:900px;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 8</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
   <li>Item 11</li>
   <li>Item 12</li>
   <li>Item 13</li>
   <li>Item 14</li>
   <li>Item 15</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**Be viewed in fullPage mode**

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately your suggestion produces a list that aligns per row - i need a solution that aligns the entries per column like in a dictionary (see my example).

Answer (score 0):

This is what u want, Happy Coding!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <style>
    body{
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">First item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">Second item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">Third item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">fourth item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">fifth item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 list-group-item">sixth item</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Exactly the result u wanted

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately your suggestion produces a list that aligns per row - i need a solution that aligns the entries per column like in a dictionary (see my example).

Comment: @Raggamuffin whether you align it row wise or column wise, either way u will get same result